# Convert CSV to CSV MS-Dos Extension

Tags: c#, csv, ssis, dos

I have a process in SSIS that outputs SQL table data to CSV format. However, I want the output CSV in CSV (MS-DOS). Is there a way I can convert the normal CSV file to CSV (MS-DOS) ? (Like C# code that would convert the extension/type) . I tried using the option available in visual studio in SSIS, and couldn't find the solution towards it. Your help is appreciated.

By default, the output format is in CSV(Comma delimited, highlighted blue). I want that to be converted to CSV(MS-DOS, highlighted yellow).

[image]

Comment: csv's are Comma-separated values, independent of operating system, so what are you asking how to change the nre line?

Comment: What is "CSV (MS-DOS)" and how is it different than "CSV"?

Comment: @JNevill - CSV is a Comma delimited and CSV (Ms-Dos) is another extension to csv. The report I am creating requires the CSV to be in CSV(MS-DOS). I have posted the picture in this request.

Comment: @nbk - I am looking to see if CSV (Comma separated) can be converted to CSV (MS-DOS) using some C# or any other method. I have posted the picture .

Comment: only difference is encoding special characters (accents, etc), far as  I know.  It's 2022, I sincerely doubt you are going to have an OS that can't read Windows-1252

Comment: c# has a lot encoind and ever ibm437 ot os easy to convert them of course in limits  see https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.codepage?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

If this article is accurate, https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009508_Comma-Delimited_and_MS-DOS_CSV_Variations.html then getting an CSV (MS-DOS) output will be fairly straight-forward

> if you have certain special characters in text fields; for example, an accented (foreign language) character. If you export as Windows CSV, those fields are encoded using the Windows-1252 code page. DOS encoding usually uses code page 437, which maps characters used in old pre-Windows PCs.

Then you need to define 2 Flat File Connection Managers. The first will use `1252 (ANSI - Latin I)` as your code page and point to C:\ssisdata\input\File.csv. The second will use `437 (OEM - United States)` and point to C:\ssisdata\input\DOSFile.csv (this way you create a new file instead of clobbering the existing.)

Your Data Flow then becomes a Flat File Source to Flat File Destination.

Comment: I tried this. Source Flat file code page = 1252, Destination Flat file code page = 437. Data transfers successfully but doesn't actually converts the destination file to csv ms dos

Comment: Can you provide an example of a source value that does not convert to the expected value and what the expected value should be?

Comment: So, the thing is CSV(MS-DOS) file is called in a command prompt window and it generates data based on that CSV(MS-DOS). If the file isn't MS-DOS, then it doesn't generate the report. If I manually do 'Save As' CSV(MS-DOS) in notepad, then the command prompt generates the required data. You get my point ?

Comment: I see your words but that's nothing that we can reproduce to see what's awry. A command line executable consumes your CSV. When it's saved-as MS-DOS csv, it works, otherwise it doesn't. Sooo, I'd be looking at a file difference between the file generated with a 437 code page and what happens when it's saved as MS-DOS. `fc source.csv msdos.csv` and see what's kicked out. I'd also check line endings on both, etc

Comment: You said. Data transfers successfully but doesn't actually converts the destination file to csv ms dos. How do you tell?

Comment: What is the visible sign that it is not csv-msdos but csv?